# Composer: how to install `dev` packages in Symfony 2.3?

Tags: composer-php, symfony-2.3

Trying to install the [KnpGaufretteBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle) in a Symfony 2.3 project, I'm having no luck. The problem is:

1. `minimum-stability:stable` (in `composer.json`);
2. the bundle I require is `dev-master` version still.

Reading [this](http://symfony.com/blog/upgrading-your-symfony-projects-the-easy-way) in the Symfony docs was frustrating:

> If you know of a cool bundle or PHP library that still requires a dev
>   minimum stability, talk to the lead developer and convince him to tag
>   a stable release.

I'm not changing the minimum stability of the *whole* project to `dev`, as it would certainly make a *huge* mess - I mean, **can't I use stable packages and dev packages side by side?**

Am I missing something about composer maybe?

---

**Edit (14 August 2013)**

According to [Sven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1627406/sven)'s answer below, I've edited my `composer.json` (you can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/paolostefan/6229204)) and it started to work. Anyway, this is a partial solution, because inline aliases do not work for dependencies - so in my case I'd have to specify all dependencies of "less-than-stable" packages first, and alias them one by one.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

just use

```
"knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle": "dev-master@dev"
```

if you need the latest dev version

you can also change minimum-stability to dev and add "prefer-stable": true like this:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
```

then composer will always try to find a stable version and if nothing found install dev, so your symfony packages will be still stable.
But in your case composer will install v0.1.4 (latest stable of knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle), so you need dev-master@dev anyway. prefer-stable is just a hint for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at aliases: http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md

They are supposed to allow you to address a branch (which by definition is always in development, because you can only access the latest commit) in a way that that branch should be the logical extension of a version tag.

For a yet untagged project, a proper assumed tag version would be like "0.0.0".

You should try the inline alias for the bundle.

Comment: Edited my question - thx for the info. Anyway changing the version string (see the gist) from dev-master to 0.0.0 (or 2.*, according to the `extra` section ) didn't change anything

Comment: Stupid me: I was updating the wrong composer.json. In fact, `dev-master as 0.0.0` on this bundle and its dependencies did solve the issue. I'm accepting the other answer though, as it's more flexible (no need to specify aliased dependencies). Thanks a lot anyway!