# dev-master symfony2 composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I don't won't to repeat questions, but i have the same problem as the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214600/composer-how-to-install-dev-packages-in-symfony-2-3)
but my problem couldn't be solved by the supplied answers. I'm not installing a symfony bundle but my own dependendy, just to test if it works in symfony2. composer.json is [on this link](https://github.com/MarioLegenda/ImageUploader/blob/master/composer.json)

In composer.json of Symfony 2.4, i tried a lot of ways to resolve this problem...
Adding

> "dev-master@dev"

then alias like in the question above

```
dev-master as 0.0.0
```

I also tried changing `minimum-stability` to `stable` but it didn't work. Composer says that `my requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages`. What can i do to install my dependency beacuse even `stable` doesn't work? I don't know if that's important, but I also use Symfony2 Finder in my project but Composer doesn't says it's ok.

**EDIT:** The entire error message...

```
 Problem 1
- Installation request for symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.4.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-standard-edition[2.4.x-dev].
- Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v2.5.0
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.5.0
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.6
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.5
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.4
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.3
- Installation request for mario-legenda/image-uploader dev-master -> satisfiable by mario-legenda/image-uploader[dev-master].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.2
- mario-legenda/image-uploader dev-master requires symfony/finder 2.3.* -> satisfiable    by symfony/finder[v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15,   v2.3.16, v2.3.2, v2.3
 3, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9].
- don't install symfony/finder v2.3.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/finder v2.3.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/finder v2.3.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/finder v2.3.11|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/finder v2.3.12|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/finder v2.3.13|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/finder v2.3.14|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/finder v2.3.15|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/finder v2.3.16|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
```

Comment: What's in your composer.json and what's the complete error message?

Comment: Link to composer.json is in the first sentence

Comment: Please try with `~2.3` instead of `2.3.*`.

Comment: In my composer.json or the symfonyies? Mine doesn't have a version, it's dev-master. And if you meant on Symfony Finder I am using 2.3.*

Comment: In yours, for symfony/finder.

Comment: No. Tried it and it still doesn't work. I tried it without Finder but still doesn't work