# Steam Authentication with Symfony

Tags: authentication, symfony, steam

I am working on a project that i want to connect to Steam in order to pull info based on the logged in user - my application is running Symfony 3 and i have found a bundle on git that i would like to use in order to validate and log a user into my site.

here is the bundle - https://github.com/SirWaddles/SteamAuthBundle

Because there is no composer package i have cloned the bundle into my src/ folder that sits along side my AppBundle - enabled in the appKernal and hooked up the config and security as stated in the bundle - i now get the following error

```
The service "steam.user_service" has a dependency on a non-existent service "guzzle.client.steam_user".
```

Now i know this is being called in from the following services class

```
services:
steam.user_provider:
    class: SteamAuthBundle\Security\User\SteamUserProvider
    arguments: [ '@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager', '@steam.user_service', '%steam_auth.user_class%' ]

steam.security.authentication.provider:
    class: SteamAuthBundle\Security\Authentication\SteamProvider
    arguments: [ '@steam.user_provider', '@guzzle.client.steam' ]
    public: false

steam.security.authentication.listener:
    class: SteamAuthBundle\Security\Firewall\SteamListener
    arguments: [ 'home', '@security.token_storage', '@security.authentication.manager', '@router' ]
    public: false

steam.security.authentication.entry_point:
    class: SteamAuthBundle\Security\EntryPoint\SteamEntryPoint
    arguments: [ '@security.http_utils' ]
    public: false

steam.user_service:
    class: SteamAuthBundle\Service\SteamUserService
    arguments: [ '@guzzle.client.steam_user', '%steam_auth.steam_key%' ]
```

now of course the guzzle service is causing issues, but i have no experience with Guzzle -  i kind of have a small idea of the bases of it but can anyone point out anything obvious that i may have missed? any help would be appreciated or pointers!

Comment: If you look in the composer.json file you will find that the bundle is dependent on something called: eightpoints/guzzle-bundle Are you sure there is no composer package?  If so then look on the composer site to see how to install from a git repository.  Doing so will then install all the necessary dependencies and leave everything under vendors.   The package does exist: https://packagist.org/packages/sirwaddles/steamauth There are no stable releases. Need to use the dev version. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214600/composer-how-to-install-dev-packages-in-symfony-2-3

Comment: Hey @Cerad Thanks for the reply! i was aware of the composer package before but not familiar of using the dev-master branch so thank you! Turns out the the package that the bundle im trying to use which is called 'eightpoints/guzzle-bundle ' requires php -v 5.6 but im running 7 - this is a bit of a pain :/ but again thank you for the progress :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-for anyone who ends up here in the future-

Turns out my problem was that i was running php 7.0 on my box - i downgraded to 5.6 as i had no real need to be on 7 apart from the speed

i then updated my vendors and things clicked into place